# Submit form on enter

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

How do I make this submit on pressing the enter key? I want to completely remove the submit button.

HTML

```
<form class="iform">
<input id='input1' name='input1'/>
<input type='button' value='GO!' id='submit' onclick='onSubmit()' />
</form>
```

JS

```
$('#submit').click(function() { 
$('#slider').anythingSlider($("#input1").val()); 
});
```

Comment: You should remove  `onclick='onSubmit()'` for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple since you have only one field

EITHER

```
<form class="iform" id="iform">
<input id='input1' name='input1'/>
<input type='submit' value='GO!'  />
</form>
```

OR even

```
<form class="iform" id="iform">
<input id='input1' name='input1'/>
</form>
```

JS in either case

```
$('#iform').submit(function(e) {   
  $('#slider').anythingSlider($("#input1").val());
  e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Hitting "enter" while focused in the text field will already submit the form, you don't actually *need* the submit button (look at Stack Overflow's "search" form at the top right of this page for example). You just might need to change your javascript to listen to the `submit` event instead:

```
$('form').submit(function() { 
   $('#slider').anythingSlider($("#input1").val()); 
});
```

If you want the form submitted when someone presses enter *regardless of where the focus is*, I would suggest against it. It's extremely confusing behavior and can easily be triggered by accident.

Comment: You must cancel the submit or the page will change

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#formId').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.which == 13)
      $('#slider').anythingSlider($("#input1").val());            }
     return false;
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

a normal form is automatically submitted when pressing enter.

```
<form id="form1" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" name="input1" />
</form>
```

this should work fine, but it may not validate.

If you want to submit your form in javascript, you can use the .submit() function.

```
document.forms["form1"].submit();
```

or jQuery

```
$("#form1").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<input type="submit" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution without the submit button:

HTML

```
<form action="path_to_the_action">
  <input class="submit_on_enter" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit_on_enter').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            this.form.submit();
            return false;
         }
    });
  });
</script>
```